# Python / Flask -- server is receiving POST requests as GET requests

Tags: python, flask, postman

I created an endpoint in the flask file that looks like this

```
@app.route("/update", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def update_func():
    results = {
        "method": request.method
    }
    return json.dumps(results)
```

I tried calling this function using both Postman and python, both are saying Flask is processing it as a get request.

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://site.fakeurl.org/update", json={})
print r.json()
```

Is there a config file I need to change for this process as a POST request?

Is this happening to anyone else?

Comment: Have you sure you restarted your flask server or are running in debug mode? Do you have any kind of caching layer? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: It does not fit your code, but this usually happens when the route ends on a slash and you request it without the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using http://www.site.faekurl.org/update ?

Some servers redirect http:// to http://www.-- and as a result, the POST request + it's data gets lost in the process.